# Taxonomy terms are not checked when edit custom post

Tags: taxonomy

The taxonomy terms selected are saved but when I edit post the taxonomy terms are no checked again, Does anyone know why this happens?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you view your Console when you're on the editing page, are there any JS errors?

Comment: @WebElaine No errors are shown